# Regex : I want to match multiple words after the particular character (like '?') .The matching strings will be any where and any order

Tags: regex

```
curl -vL http://www.yyyy.com/index.html?event_id=100&stream_id&vbegin&vend&p&fps&m&f&cc&mta&channel&outlet&plang&fs=10
```

This is my URL. I want to match `event_id,fs,stream_id`(these are parameters) strings after a character('?') and I want to remove remaining parameters using regex. But the URL may like

curl -vL http://www.yyyy.com/index.html?vbegin=100&&vend&p&fps&m&event_id=10&fs=10

also.parameters will be in any order or it may not be there. So I want to match the given parameter and if its present let it be and if it does not present any no need to do any action. Then I need to remove the remaining parameters and its values.

Comment: what regex have you tried and what will your sample input and output look like

Comment: my sample input is
 
curl -vL http://www.yyyy.com/index.html?event_id=100&stream_id&vbegin&vend&p&fps&m&f&cc&mta&channel&outlet&plang&fs=10 

I want to match plang and fs and remaining parameters i need to ignore.

sample output is

curl -vL http://www.yyyy.com/index.html?plang&fs=10

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @Aadhithaneswaramoorthy Show sample input and output and edit your question,So that everyone will understand

Comment: my sample input is curl -vL  yyyy.com/index.html?m&f&cc&mta&channel&outlet&plang&fs=10 I want to match plang and fs and remaining parameters i need to ignore. sample output is curl -vL  yyyy.com/index.html?plang&fs=10

Comment: Try this https://regex101.com/r/XBwp3E/1

Comment: But those parameters are in any order . not in same order . It may like

curl -vL yyyy.com/index.html?m&f&cc&mta&channel&outlet&fs&plang=10

or
curl -vL yyyy.com/index.html?m&fs=10&cc&mta&channel&outlet&plang

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XBwp3E/2

Comment: Thank you so much. But I have one more query. Suppose if we i want to match another 2 parameters means what i have to do. suppose the another 2 parameter is channel and mta

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/XBwp3E/3

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
import re
s='http://www.yyyy.com/index.html? 
event_id=100&stream_id&vbegin&vend&p&fps&m&f&cc&mta&channel&outlet&plang&fs=10'
args=re.sub("(.*)\\?(.*)","\\2",s)
EVENT_PAT = ".*event_id=(\d+).*"
eventpat=re.compile(EVENT_PAT)
event_id = eventpat.match(args).group(1)
FS_PAT = ".*fs=(\d+).*"
fspat = re.compile(FS_PAT)
fs_id = fspat.match(args).group(1)
```

Although this is not an optimal solution it should work. You can also try to split args by & and iterate over the list and split by '=' to make it like a key-value pair and access any keys.

```
list_args = args.split('&')
hm={}
for args in list_args:
    if len(args.split("="))>1: hm[args.split("=")[0]]=args.split("=")[1]
print(hm)
```

Comment: I want these in regex alone. Because i am going to use these in xml file

Answer (score 0):

How about a perl solution like below:

```
> export URL="curl -vL http://www.yyyy.com/index.html?event_id=100&stream_id&vbegin&vend&p&fps&m&f&cc&mta&channel&outlet&plang&fs=10"
> perl -pe 'BEGIN {$x=$ENV{URL};@reqd=("event_id=","stream_id","fs=");foreach $url (@reqd) { if($x=~m/$url([^&]*)(\&|$)/sm) {print "$&\n"}}exit}'
event_id=100&
stream_id&
fs=10
> export URL="curl -vL http://www.yyyy.com/index.html?vbegin=100&&vend&p&fps&m&event_id=10&fs=10"
> perl -pe 'BEGIN {$x=$ENV{URL};@reqd=("event_id=","stream_id","fs=");foreach $url (@reqd) { if($x=~m/$url([^&]*)(\&|$)/sm) {print "$&\n"}}exit}'
event_id=10&
fs=10
>
```